# python-twitter retrieving all followers

Tags: python, python-twitter

I'm using the [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) library and while I can get the code to retrieve a 'set' of results, apparently in the first 'page' ... I for the life of me can't find the right code to get a set of ALL the followers for a specific account/handle.

I'm using this snip...

```
target = sys.argv[1]

#returns a twitter.User instance for each follower
users = api.GetFollowers(target) 
print [u.screen_name for u in users]
```

I'd appreciate any pointers, if someone's figured this out already?

Thanks in advance.
/Raf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=20#c3), I guess it has been fixed. Check this [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=20#c3).